# Rendering Dynamic HTML using "react-native-pell-rich-editor" module

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

Good day!

I would like to ask if someone know how to render the HTML dynamically after passing a props from my customized component. since I only noticed that initialContentHTML props can render HTML when the component is on mount stage.

Thank you!

```
// My Component
const CheckboxDetails = (props) => {
const {
    currentIndex = 0,
    onChangeRichText,
    richTextRef,
    initialContentHTML,
    disabled,
  } = props;


  // Rich Text Component from "react-native-pell-rich-editor"  
    <RichEditor
      ref={(el) => { return richTextRef.current[currentIndex] = el; }}
      useContainer={false}
      containerStyle={{ minHeight: height }}
      onChange={onChangeRichText}
      editorInitializedCallback={editorInitializedCallback}
      initialContentHTML={initialContentHTML}                    
      disabled={disabled}
    />
}

export default CheckboxDetails
```

I was planning to change another module, however it will take longer to modify our system and might as well affect some part of our system.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you try to clarify the question a little? I'm not quite sure what you are asking here. Also, your component doesn't seem to actually return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ref` you can call html modification method `setContentHTML` or `insertHTML`

```js
const editor = useRef(null);

const changeHTML = () => editor.current?.setContentHTML('some HTML here')

<RichEditor
  ref={editor}
  initialContentHTML={'Hello <b>World</b> <p>this is a new paragraph</p> <p>this is another new paragraph</p>'}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kirill Novikov. It has been solve on this approach. However, I use "sendAction" method since setContentHTML is not exist on their module.

Comment: @GavinCanete probably you need to use `editor.current?.setContentHTML` my bad